# How Do I Update An Existing War/Jar/Zip File Using Gradle?

Tags: jakarta-ee, gradle

I need to make a copy of an existing war file and update an xml file within it.
My thoughts on how to do this are:

- Extract file from existing war
- Replace String in file
- Copy war
- Add modified file back to copied war

I can do the first 3 steps with Gradle but I can only work out how to do the last step with Ant.

```
task updateWar() << {
    def originalWar = file("deploy/mywar.war")
    def outputDir = file("deploy")
    def wars = [ "war1", "war2" ]
    wars.each() { warFile ->        
        delete "deploy/WEB-INF/ejb.xml"
        copy {
            //Step 1
            from(zipTree(originalWar)) {
                include 'WEB-INF/ejb.xml'
            }
            into outputDir
            //Step 2
            filter{
                String line -> line.replaceAll("<value>OriginalText</value>",
                        "<value>UpdatedText</value>")
            }
        }
        //Step 3
        copy {
            from outputDir
            into outputDir
            include 'mywar.war'
            rename 'mywar.war',"${warFile}.war"
        }       
        //Step 4
        ant.jar(update: "true", destfile: deploy/${warFile}.war") {
            fileset(dir: deploy", includes: 'WEB-INF/**')
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally there would be a filter option that allowed me to modify the specified file when I was copying but I haven't worked that out yet.

How do you do this effectively in Gradle without falling back to Ant? Is even a groovy gradle way to do it in one step?

Edit:
I have got closer. A Zip task using a ziptree from the original war was the first key step. The filesMatching combined with the filter was the secret sauce! However, I can't use this in a loop like I can the copy method so I'm still stuck :(

```
task updateWar(type: Zip) {
    def originalWar = file("deploy/mywar.war")
    def outputDir = file("deploy")
    archiveName = "war2.war"
    destinationDir = outputDir
    from (zipTree(originalWar),{
        filesMatching("WEB-INF/ejb.xml") {
            filter{
                String line -> line.replaceAll("<value>OriginalText</value>",
                        "<value>UpdatedText</value>")
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Why you want to iterate over? It seems that it can be done.

Comment: You can't call tasks like methods in gradle and I actually have 9 similar wars that I need to update so I don't want to copy and paste the same block 9 times (I'm modifying a third party build that doesn't use the war plugin so I can't do it in the normal way)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want to replace the original file within the `war` with one in the `res` folder, here is how to do it:

```
task updateWar(type: Zip) {
    def originalWar = file("deploy/mywar.war")

    archiveBaseName = 'mywar'
    archiveExtension = 'war'

    from(zipTree(originalWar)) {
        // Remove the original ejb.xml if it exists
        exclude("**/WEB-INF/ejb.xml")
    }

    // Include our own ejb.xml
    from('res/ejb.xml') {
        into('WEB-INF/')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Gradle 7.x you can replace archive (zip) files via [DuplicatesStrategy](https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:duplicatesStrategy).
It does not provide 'override' strategy, buy you can achieve the same result with 'exclude' strategy and reversed copy order. Like this:

```
task updateWar(type: Zip) {
    ...
    duplicatesStrategy 'exclude'
    // First copy the overriding files.
    from('res/ejb.xml') {
        into('WEB-INF/')
    }
    // Then copy the common content.
    // (duplicate files it will be skipped)
    from(zipTree(originalWar)) {
        ...
    }
}
```